# Mathematics chat now available

Tags: discussion, chat

Just a heads-up; Mathematics now has access to a [third place](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/), to chat in more real-time way via [chat.stackexchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com).

Please feel free to drop by. The "chat" link should appear at the top of all Mathematics (not meta) pages, and the chat room itself will appear in the sidebar.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36

Comment: Maybe there can be a better name than "Talking Numbers"?

Comment: @JM: Please suggest :)

Comment: What's wrong with just "Mathematics"?

Comment: @Rahul @JM - local mods like @KennyTM can rename easily. And note you aren't limited to one room.

Comment: It would be great to provide a link to "chat" on the top bar in the meta site. It is there in the main site, but it is missing in meta.

Answer (score 3):

There's no question, so this isn't an answer. It's a suggestion the moderators-to-be might want to consider.

One site I participate in uses an associated IRC channel so that users can quickly ask the mods, who are almost always in the room, stuff about proper topics, or to point out any site peculiarities (e.g. a broken page or a rampaging spammer).

I would suggest, then, that for the current associated chat room to be more useful than it currently is, that it be a place where you can get a quick response from the moderators for any site-related questions (i.e., when you're too impatient to wait for answers on meta).

Just a thought...

Comment: M.: while this is a good idea in principle, it may be slightly difficult for the moderators (only 3 to be elected!) to constantly hang out in chat. Also a constant monitoring by the moderators, I think, is somewhat contrary to the principle of minimal moderator interference that many on Meta seem to have preferred.

Comment: I'm certainly not suggesting "constantly", @Willie; just that they might be "there" whenever they can be. Though, I would suppose that there would indeed be questions that are better asked on meta rather than just being directed at a moderator.

Comment: (BTW [not trying to be presumptuous, just that since I am a candidate, might as well get this out of the way]: if anyone ever wants to contact me, the fastest way would be to send me an e-mail. My address can be easily found following the link in my user page. )

Comment: M.: fair enough. Besides, it seems a bit of a pity that hardly anyone ever uses the chat for anything.